# prove that the inner product of path and velocity is zero

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval.
A function $\gamma : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ is called a path and we write $\gamma (t)=(\gamma^{1}(t),\ldots,\gamma^{m}(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
If all m components are differentiable functions from $I \ \mbox{to} \ \mathbb{R}^m$,then the path is a differentiable path. Then for every $t \in I$, we consider $\gamma'(t)=((\gamma^{1})'(t),\ldots,(\gamma^{m})'(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ which is called the velocity vector of $\gamma$ at t.

Question: if $\gamma:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a differentiable path and $||\gamma(t)||=1, \ \forall t \in I$. We fix a point $t_0 \in I$ and denote $\gamma(t_0):=\vec{a},\gamma'(t_0):=\vec{q}$ Prove that $$<\vec{a},\vec{q}>=0$$

My method is to use $0\leq |<\vec{a},\vec{q}>| \leq ||\vec{a}|| ||\vec{q}||=||\vec{q}||$, then by squeeze theorem, we can have the inner product equals zero. However, as you see, my method does not work.

Comment: In general, the inner product of a path and its velocity is nonzero.  The extra conditions are key to proving this fact.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Differentiate the function $t \mapsto \langle \gamma(t), \gamma(t) \rangle$.

Comment: Additional hint: the inner product is a dot product is a *PRODUCT*, so there's a product rule.

Comment: the hints given by you two are very useful , now i know what to do. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.